# If U is a T-invariant subspace of V is there necessarily another T-invariant subspace$-W S.T. U\oplus W = V?$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Suppose $V$ is a vector space over $\Bbb F, T:V\to V$ is a linear operator  and $U$ is a T-invariant subspace of V. is there necessarily another T-invariant subspace$-\,W\,\,  S.T. \,U\oplus W = V?$

I suspect this is in fact not true but cannot come up with a counter example.

Comment: There is even a 2-dimensional counterexample.  Think about it, and you cannot miss :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Work out the details in the following example:

$$T:\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R^2\;,\;\;T\binom xy:=\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{pmatrix}\binom xy$$

You can check the only eigenvalue of $\;T\;$ is $\;\lambda=1\;$, and thus there is a $\;T\,-$ invariant space, $\;U:=$ Span$\,\left\{\,\binom x0\,\right\}\;$, which is the eigenspace of the above eigenvalue.

Well, if there were another $\;T\,-$ invariant space $\;W\;$ s.t. $\;\Bbb R^2=U\oplus W\;$ , then $\;T\;$ would have another eigenvalue different from $\;1\;$ ....but this is not so.